# MongoDB's C# Driver not working precisely when query datetime

Tags: c#, mongodb

There is a document in my MongoDB:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5624e8c8470b460f1cf1c323"),
  "body" : "【ex】test",
  "datetime" : ISODate("2015-10-19T12:57:41.836Z"),
  "source" : "wx",
  "title" : "for test"
}
```

And Here is my Query method:

```
public Task<List<InfoLogModel>> GetLogByFilter(DateTime? startAt = null, DateTime? endAt = null)
{
    var collection = //...
    List<FilterDefinition<InfoLogModel>> QueryConditionList = new List<FilterDefinition<InfoLogModel>>();
    if (startAt != null)
        QueryConditionList.Add(Builders<InfoLogModel>.Filter.Gte(aa => aa.datetime, (BsonDateTime)startAt));
    if (endAt != null)
        QueryConditionList.Add(Builders<InfoLogModel>.Filter.Lte(aa => aa.datetime, (BsonDateTime)endAt));
    var filter = Builders<InfoLogModel>.Filter.And(QueryConditionList);
    return collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
}
```

It's pretty strange that when my `startAt` is `DateTime.Parse("2015/10/20")`,  the result count is 0 which is fine.

But when I set `startAt = DateTime.Parse("2015/10/19 20:00:00")`, I surprisly got the document.

The document's `datetime` is 2015/10/19 12:57:41, When I can get the document even though I filterd it?

Comment: What's your time zone? `datetime` is in UTC but `startAt` is in your local time.

Comment: @JohnnyHK  Yes. That's where goes wrong. Thanks.